# Python doesn't recognise twilio in my computer

Tags: python, twilio

[image]

I downloaded twilio in the terminal but python said there's no twilio module. Did I do something wrong here? Thanks for answering.

Comment: How exactly did you download and install it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Burhan, I used "sudo easy_install twilio" to the terminal to install twilio.

Comment: Don't paste images, paste actual traceback

Comment: Please use `sudo pip install twilio` as per the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) and try again.